# New Form is not accessing in my project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am a new programmer of C#.net I've been working on a project already have 6 to 7 forms in it on which I am working, last night when I add new form and try to access directly to this form in program.cs file then neither there is frmForm1 suggestion is coming and if I write it manually then the error arise

> Error 2 , The type or namespace name 'frmForm2' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\SurveyBuilder\SurveyBuilder\Program.cs   29  37  SurveyBuilder

Whenever there is a form named Form2.cs is in my project, tried to attach snap of it but due to low reputation(its my first question on this site) I am not able to attach.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THe form frmForm2 is in a different namespace than the code in program.cs. Check if the namespace statement is the same in both files

Comment: Check Program.cs and newly added form has same namespace. you will found it above class declaration.

Comment: @Steve dear here is my code of form2, i have not worked on it yet just simply added it, code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: @user2532775 Are all of your other files using `namespace SurveyBuilder`?

Comment: Please add it to the question (click the edit link) because in comments you can't format the code. However, it is clear that you use the namespace `SurveyBuilder`, then program.cs should have the same namespace (pay attention to case)

Comment: @user2532775  yes all of my forms including program.cs namespace is SurveyBuilder

Comment: @Steve i don't know how to add it to the question :( because i am new here, i try to click on edit option but there i am not able to find how to put it into the question category....

Comment: @user2532775 Can you post some of the code from `form1`? So we can make sure the namespaces and references are ok.

Comment: here is the code of Form2:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: @gwin003 I've commented above the code of Form2

Comment: The error mentions `frmForm2`, but class name is `Form2`. Did you try to declare variable as `Form2 frmForm2 = new Form2();`?

Comment: Please add the code where you are declaring your Form2 variable to your question, showing the Class for Form2 is telling us nothing. i.e. `Form2 frmForm2 = new Form2` You should have something like that somewhere in your program.

Comment: thanks for all of ya :) I've solved my problem :) thanks a lot